# Did JPMC CEO author the circulated letter to 25 y.o. golddigger?

Tags: quotes

I have seen [this publication](http://www.worthytoshare.com/pretty-girl-seeking-rich-husband-reply-got-banker-priceless) in many editions posted on FB and other sources.  While the reply to her is brilliant and priceless, I have a hard time believing that the CEO of such major visibility as [Jamie Dimon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Dimon) would put his public persona on the line for something like that.  Can anybody confirm or submit any supporting material pointing to either confirm or debunk this?

Answer (score 8):

[Snopes.com](http://www.snopes.com/love/dating/golddigger.asp) investigated and reported that the original letter was posted to Craigslist in 2007, apparently genuinely.

The response, however, was anonymous. It has since been falsely attributed to a number of people.

> One of them, an investment banker with J.P. Morgan Chase & Co., was fingered more often than the others as the most likely author. His firm, however, denied that the banker so named (who did indeed work for that entity) did anything more than forward the message to friends, an act that inserted his signature block into the fray and caused some to take him for the originator of the piece.